# ReactiveUI WhenAny fails to fire when compiled in VS 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, msbuild, reactiveui

I'm using Reactive UI with a simple example.

I want a button's command to be enabled when a user types the correct phrase into a text box. I've set up the view model as follows:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ReactiveObject, IMainWindowViewModel
{
    private string _text;
    private bool? _isCorrect;
    private IReactiveCommand _closeCommand;
    private readonly IObservable<bool> _canClose;

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        _canClose = this.WhenAny(c => c.IsCorrect, (c) =>
            { 
                // this fires once on initialization if compiled in VS 2010.
                return c.Value == true;
            });

        //var canClose = this.WhenAny(m => m.Text, c =>
        // {
        // return "Correct Text".Equals(c.Value);
        // });
        this.CloseCommand = new ReactiveCommand( _canClose);
        this.CloseCommand.Subscribe(c => Debug.WriteLine("Ok pressed"));
    }

    public IReactiveCommand CloseCommand
    {
        get { return _closeCommand; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _closeCommand, value); }
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set
        {
            this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _text, value);
            CheckTextStatus();
        }
    }

    public bool? IsCorrect
    {
        get { return _isCorrect; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _isCorrect, value); }
    }

    private void CheckTextStatus()
    {
        this.IsCorrect = null;
        if (Text.Equals("Correct Text"))
        {
            this.IsCorrect = true;
        }
        else if (!"Correct Text".StartsWith(Text))
        {
            this.IsCorrect = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using Reactive UI 4.6 because we have to support XP (.NET 4.0) for a while longer.

The `_canClose WhenAny` only fires once on initialization and never fires when the `IsCorrect` property changes.

However, this behaviour only occurs when compiling in VS 2010. If I compile in VS2012 or with MSBuild it works correctly.

I'm assuming it has something to do with the BCL .target MSBuild task, but not sure exactly what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because `[CallerMethodName]` only works when compiling via VS2012, you need to use a different overload of `RaiseAndSetIfChanged` if you want to compile on VS2010. Something like:

```
bool? _IsCorrect;  // The naming is Significant
public bool? IsCorrect {
    get { return _IsCorrect; }
    set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(x => x.IsCorrect, value); }
}
```

Comment: However, this is deprecated in RxUI 5.0, correct? We should stick with the `this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _isCorrect, value)` for future-proofing (and get rid of VS2010) ?

Comment: If you can get rid of VS2010, that's definitely the best option :)  Since RxUI 5.0 is .NET 4.5+ only, it can depend on `[CallerMethodName]` working, so it deprecates all of the alternatives, except for the raw methods `raisePropertyChang[ing/ed]`, which you should really only use in tooling or other codegen scenarios